# Does pulling or pushing take more effort?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In which case is more effort needed: when you push or when you pull?

We have a common experience that man tends to first push anything. How it is justified and what are the reasons behind this?

Comment: LOL, you can only pull something if it has handles and if your hands or fingers or whatever you may insert to the handles are strong enough. Pushing always works.

Comment: Can you clarify what question you're asking about physics? At the momnt the question seems to be about human psychology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is easier, pushing or pulling?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1317/)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically (under identical situations) there is no difference between pull and push.

However, when we pull something, a vertical component of our applied force is opposite to the weight of, say, a block; which reduces the net weight and it feels as if it is easier to pull the box than pushing it. This case holds true under certain assumptions only. Ponder on them.